# Start a new thread in a specific process

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, python-multithreading, python-multiprocessing

I am starting a process like so:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

proc = Process(target=foo)
proc.start()
```

Is it now possible to start a new thread inside that process? If so, is it only possible from say, the function `foo`, or can I somehow do this by just knowing the pid of the process(with proc.pid for instance)? proc itself doesn't have any methods like `proc.start_new_thread` or anything like that.

Comment: afaik, using the multiprocessing module, it can only be done inside the target function. Maybe, you can create a wrapper for foo that handles the threading, and use that wrapper as the target ?

Comment: That's certainly worth a try, thanks. I do find it odd that this isn't straightforward. But I'm new to multi-threading/multi-processing.